# How to make my open source project's web domain bus-proof?

Tags: website

If I suddenly die, my small open source project will survive (after all, the source code is open), but it can be hurt quite badly: The project's web domain is owned by me and it could become cybersquatted.

We are just a bunch of individuals who have never met. There is no overall organization/foundation. Patches get submitted by companies and individuals who have their own agenda that might or might not include openness.

- Is there a commonly established practice to handle this?
- For instance, is there a kind of open source foundation that would accept to handle domain ownership/fallback in some way? In normal times it would do nothing, but when I die it would identify the core developers, contact them and established a transfer strategy.

Comment: I'm torn between upvoting this, and flagging it as off-topic :(

Comment: @kdopen: I believe the problem described is specific to open source. Proprietary software almost always have a company behind, or an individual not specially interested in the common good.

Comment: That's why I'm torn. It's also asking for external resources ('a kind of open source foundation') which i generally a big no-no on SO, and gets involved in legal areas like will probate - if you 'own' the domain name, then it is part of your estate.

Comment: @kdopen: The most similar existing site is probably [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com), and questions asking for external resources/platforms are highly appreciated there.

Comment: I actually rescued a project from oblivion. The original site went offline and I had a copy on an old hard drive. I uploaded it to GitHub. It's no longer active, but the code has been preserved.

Answer (score 6):

**You might be able to try one of the following.**

- Use a shared repository like GitHub or similar and then your domain name is not required for the project to continue i.e. graceful degradation of service.
- Try gifting the domain name to a reliable/established group (might need to pay for a few years domain ownership first).
- Don't rely on the domain name at all.
- Gift the code to Apache or Eclipse if you can.
- Gift the code to FSF if GPLv3 or LGPL is OK.
- Put it in your will / talk to your next of kin about it.

This is a real issue, but it also applies to company-backed open source and proprietary code, I have tracked down code that is supported by companies that don't exist / bought by Medical Device Manufacturers (experience talking), Open Source that is now off the web (yes it can happen) and similar.

And does it really matter in the end?

Comment: Very interesting advice about not using a website in the first place! Apache/Eclipse have very steep requirements. As for your final question, I guess it matters, as the website usually shows the "latest release" for download, which might actually have critical security flaws patched elsewhere. Skilled cybersquatters might even mirror the past website and offer the same binaries infected with malware once they get control of the domain.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - there's a term for that - **SourceForgery**.

Comment: I assumed that your **hosting** would survive your death (i.e. sourceforge), but if not hosted at souceforge/google code, then you probably need some alternative.

Comment: Did you know that google code is being discontinued?

Comment: No I didn't know Google Code was being discontinued. Thanks @congusbongus

Comment: I'm not comfortable with recommending people use sourceforge: [**Why open source projects are fleeing sourceforge**](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2938017/why-big-open-source-projects-are-fleeing-sourceforges-free-software-hub.html)

Comment: The main business of an OSS project is to publish sourcecode, so the problems reported for SourceForge do not apply to OSS as I cannot see any problem reported for source code publishing. Be careful with companies that only have a business background, as they may give up a service without a longer announcement. This may e.g. apply to github.

Comment: @Andrew Russell - You propose the FSF but even today, the FSF is de-facto a one man show and may change their intent without announcement. If you like to understand the problems I have in mind, I recommend you to search the net for what happened to `gtar` in the mid-1990s. After the PD-TAR/SUG-TAR project from the Sun employee John Gilmore was given to the FSF, the maintainers changed on a year by year base for the following 12 years as a result of the policy from the FSF leadership. There are still active bugs inside that result from these frequent changes.